Slurm: using GPU sharding
I cannot use GPU sharding, even though everything seems to have been configured according to the instructions:
$ scontrol show node compute01
NodeName=compute01 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=32
   CPUAlloc=48 CPUEfctv=128 CPUTot=128 CPULoad=10.95
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:8,shard:32
   [truncated]

When using gres:gpu everything works perfectly:
$ /usr/bin/srun --gres=gpu:2 ls
srun: job 192 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 192 has been allocated resources
(...)

However, when using sharding, it just stays waiting indefinitely:
$ /usr/bin/srun --gres=shard:2 ls
srun: job 193 queued and waiting for resources

The reason it gives for pending is just "Resources":
$ scontrol show job 193
JobId=193 JobName=ls
   UserId=rpcruz(1000) GroupId=rpcruz(1000) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=1 Nice=0 Account=account QOS=normal
   JobState=PENDING Reason=Resources Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=0 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:00:00 TimeLimit=2-00:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2024-06-28T05:36:51 EligibleTime=2024-06-28T05:36:51
   AccrueTime=2024-06-28T05:36:51
   StartTime=2024-06-29T18:13:22 EndTime=2024-07-01T18:13:22 Deadline=N/A
   SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2024-06-28T05:37:20 Scheduler=Backfill:*
   Partition=partition AllocNode:Sid=localhost:47757
   ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=1 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   ReqTRES=cpu=1,mem=1031887M,node=1,billing=1
   AllocTRES=(null)
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=0 MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=ls
   WorkDir=/home/rpcruz
   Power=
   TresPerNode=gres/shard:2

(you may notice in the last line that the flag seems to have been set.)
Again, I think I have configured it properly -- it shows up correctly in scontrol (as shown above). Our setup is pretty simple -- I just added shard to /etc/slurm/slurm.conf:
GresTypes=gpu,shard
NodeName=compute01 Gres=gpu:8,shard:32 [truncated]

Our /etc/slurm/gres.conf is also straight-forward: (again, it works fine for --gres=gpu:1)
Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia[0-7]
Name=shard Count=32

Maybe I am just running srun improperly? Should it not just be srun --gres=shard:2 to allocate half of a GPU? (since I am using 32 shards for the 8 gpus, so it is 4 shards per GPU)
